# 'nvd3_tags' is not a valid tag library

Tags: python, django, nvd3.js

I was using django-charts nvd3 and i got this error while running

python manage.py 
runserver Error :

**TemplateSyntaxError**
**'nvd3_tags' is not a valid** 
**tag library:
 Template library nvd3_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.nvd3_tags,django_admin_bootstrapped.templatetags.nvd3_tag,django.contrib.ad**

I tried all the given solutions over the net but nothing was helpful.
I am using django 1.7.1

**the code in template was.**

```
{% load static %}
<link media="all" href="{% static 'nvd3/src/nv.d3.css' %}"     type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src='{% static 'd3/d3.min.js' %}'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='{% static 'nvd3/nv.d3.min.js'     %}'></script>
{% load nvd3_tags %}
<head>
<!--{% include_chart_jscss %}-->    
{% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra %}
</head>
<body>
<h1>Fruits vs Calories</h1>
{% include_container chartcontainer 400 600 %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add `django_nvd3` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple in your settings file.